# Easy way to mention my own blog link?

Tags: blog, links, blogger

When I need to mention a link in a post on my blog and the link is actually a link of my own blog post, I am mentioning it like this:

```
www.my_blog_name.blogspot.in/12/2013/how_to_do.html
```

If I changed my blog name then the link will be dead. So what I want is just want mention the link without my blog name.

For example, instead of:

```
www.my_blog_name.blogspot.in/12/2013/how_to_do.html
```

I want to mention it like:

```
/12/2013/how_to_do.html
```

So even if I changed my blog name, the link will work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Blogger does not support relative addressing, so this is not possible.

If you change your blog name, then:

- Blogger will change the names of links in your Pages gadget that
  point to your pages
- Blogger will not change any internal links in your blog.

So you will have to manually edit each post, look at it in HTML mode and find-and-replace any links.

This is why it's a good idea to get your blog name right (including with a custom domain) before you start writing.

Comment: fyi, I decided to investigate the issues behind this question in more depth.   The answer above does not change.  What I found, and some other relevant info, is here:   http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/Updating-internal-blogger-links-when-blog-address-changes-url.html